# Blue Imp Video Gallery not able to configure

Tags: video, gallery, blueimp

I wanted to integrate a video gallery for a client using blueimp, but i am not able to get it up and running .
I am sharing my http://jsfiddle.net/chetankumard/vEP29/ , please have a look at it and let me know what i'm missing.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        blueimp.Gallery([
            {
                title: 'KN1GHT - Last Moon',
                href: 'http://i.imgur.com/mdqQTPT.jpg'
            },
            {
                title: 'LES TWINS - An Industry Ahead',
                href: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zv9jHNwaV2E',
                type: 'text/html',
                youtube: 'zv9jHNwaV2E',
                poster: 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/zv9jHNwaV2E/0.jpg'
            },
            {
                title: 'Test',
                href: 'http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/attachments/shifting-gears/1033178d1356977973-official-non-auto-image-thread-_mg_0143.jpg'
            }
        ], {
            container: '#blueimp-gallery'

        });
    });
</script>
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">

    <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
    <div class="slides"></div>

    <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
    <h3 class="title"></h3>

    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>

    <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
    <div class="modal fade">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">

                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-body next"></div>

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                        Previous
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                        Next
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </button>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/blueimp-gallery-video.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp-gallery.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/blueimp-gallery-youtube.js"></script>
<!-- The Bootstrap Image Gallery lightbox, should be a child element of the document body -->
<link href="css/blueimp-gallery-video.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/blueimp-gallery-indicator.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/blueimp-gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```